# Cannot run a Hello-world Laravel project inside a Docker container

Tags: laravel, dockerfile

I'm trying to run a Laravel project in a docker container using Dockerfile (without the docker-compose.yml).

After I build the docker image with the following command:

```
docker build -t my-laravel-app .
```

I run it using:

```
docker run -d -p 8000:9000 --name my-laravel-container my-laravel-app
```

And when I visit: http://localhost:8000 I get

> This page isn’t workinglocalhost didn’t send any data.
> ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE

I have already tried this on two different computers (Windows WSL and Linux)

Any idea where this is stemming from?

Here is my Dockerfile:

```
# Use the official PHP image as a base
FROM php:8.2-fpm

# Install system dependencies
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \    
    git \ 
    zip \
    unzip

# Install Composer globally
RUN curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php -- --install-dir=/usr/local/bin --filename=composer

# Set the working directory
WORKDIR /var/www/html

# Copy the Laravel project files to the container
COPY . .

# Install project dependencies
RUN composer install

# Expose port 9000
EXPOSE 9000

# Start PHP-FPM
CMD ["php-fpm"]
```

Thanks in advance.